# Select option in jquery by text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This should be a fairly simple task but all the solutions online never worked for me.

I have an array that contains loan types:

```
var arrLoanType = {
        1:"Regular Loan",
        2:"Emergency Loan",
        3:"Special Loan",
        ...}
```

I compare the above to entries in the database, so that the ones existing in the database are removed from the array.

I've looped through them via the code below:

```
$.each(arrLoanType, function(index, value){
    $("#loanType").append("<option value='"+index+"'>"+value+"</option>");
});
```

Now to the question, what I want to happen is to have a default selected field based on the option's text. This is my code:

```
$('#loanType option').filter(function () { 
   return $(this).text() == selectedLoan; 
}).attr('selected','selected');
```

where `selectedLoan` is from a hidden input field `var selectedLoan = $("#loanSelected").val();`

It just doesn't work. This is how my HTML code structure looks like after the `$.each` is generated:

```
<select name="" id="loanType" class="form-control" required="">
    <option value="" selected="" disabled="" hidden="">Select Loan Type...</option>
    <option value="1">Regular Loan</option>
    <option value="2">Emergency Loan</option>
    <option value="3">Special Loan</option>
...
```

I already tried removing "selected" attribute on the first item but it still doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: arrLoanType is not an array, it is an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can select the default value on creation itself

```
$.each(arrLoanType, function(index, value){
    if(value == selectedLoan)
        $("#loanType").append("<option value='"+index+"' selected>"+value+"</option>");
    else
        $("#loanType").append("<option value='"+index+"'>"+value+"</option>");
});
```

the if else checks the text is equal to selected loan or not and add selected attribute in creation itself
I think it solves your problem

Comment: Finally! This works better since it reduces the amount of code on the script. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems fine please have a look. Any error in the console? perhaps you forget to include jquery lib or not inside doc ready?

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var arrLoanType = {
        1:"Regular Loan",
        2:"Emergency Loan",
        3:"Special Loan"}

  $.each(arrLoanType, function(index, value){
     $("#loanType").append("<option value='"+index+"'>"+value+"</option>");
  });

  $('#loanType option').filter(function () { 
     return $(this).text() == $("#loanSelected").val(); 
  }).attr('selected','selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="loanType" class="form-control" required=""></select>
<input id ="loanSelected" value="Special Loan" type="hidden">
```